# Angular Service for sharing a bunch of values with sub hierarchy

Tags: angular

I am trying to understand what is the right way to share values among all components created under a certain component hierarchy, trying to avoid transferring the relevant inputs all the way down espicially because at some nodes they are needed and some not so it becomes very ugly.

So i thought i should do somthing like:

```
@Component({
  providers: [{provide: SharedValuesService}]
})
```

In the component that is the root of the hierarchy that needs access to these values. Some of these values are @Input to the component, so I try to undertand how to set these values in the Service, should i just set them using service.valueA = this.valueA? i think not because then they would be exposed to unwanted changes (if they should be immutable thats a problem) maybe i should create a factory somehow? tried:

```
@Component({
  providers: [{provide: SharedValuesService,useFactory: this.createService}]
})
```

but it says "this" may be undefined, and also, nothing garuentees that i have all the values when the factory is being called, maybe i should inject the service on my own when i have it ready to other components to use? is that possible?

Tell me about your approach to deal with this problem (of sharing values with sub hierarchy rooted by some specific component)

Answer (score 0):

Since your service will be instanciated by the injector, it's creation cannot depend on the component. All its parameters must be injectable.

What you can do, is having default value or some kind of "non-initiated" state.